# how to redirect to error page if path has a .(dot) in Nuxt 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I created error.vue in layout directory and it work almost corectly, but if path has a dot like(http://localhost:3000/for.m) i see "Cannot GET /PATH" instead my custom error page.
[Cannot GET /PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q73V8.png)

If i change in nuxt.config.js file target to 'server' this problem disappear but adding new problems in path (http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/) i see default 404 message from browser instead my custom error page and actually i need target static.

I don`t now can i fix this with Nuxt settings or i should write custom error handler

can anyone help me with this problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in nuxt github similar request
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8715
where someone writes that it's not a bug, that is a features of static nuxt app. Either you resign this, either change 'static' to 'server'. I choose second way, with error where in _nuxt path browser return default 404 message, fixed it like this:

in nuxt.config added

```
build: {
    publicPath: 'store', // changed '_nuxt' way to 'store'
}
serverMiddleware: ['~/server-middleware/errorhandler'], // added middleware for handling error before render page
```

in server-middleware/errorhandler.js

```
import { readFileSync } from 'node:fs';
export default function (req, res, next) {
  // if it's a stuff path for take
  if (decodeURI(req.url).match(/\/_ipx.*/) || decodeURI(req.url).match(/\/store.*/)) {
    // try to find file
    try { // if the file is found, show it
      readFileSync('static/'+ req.url.match(/img.*/)[0])
      next()
    } catch (error) { // if the file hasn't been found, rederect to custom error page
      res.writeHead(301, { Location: '/404' })
      res.end()
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```